# How to impute additive outliers in time series data

Tags: r, time-series, outliers

I need to forecast daily electricity demand. It seems that the outliers in my dataset are additive as they are affected by an anomalous behavior and are not induced by a random process that also affects the subsequent observations. In this case, is it possible to impute them by the average of the previous and next observation?

Comment: Bayesian imputation is one approach.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please let me know how to do it? Which library? Is it possible to do it using the forecast library?

Comment: Since your question is looking for something in `R`, probably [RStan](https://mc-stan.org/users/interfaces/rstan). I have not made substantial use of `R` in years, so you'll have to read the docs to find out how. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯